# Can't add multiple elements per dataset in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, attributes

I'm displaying a set of circles, which works great. Now, I'd like to put a second set of circles, a bit smaller and with different style. I've tried appending to the appended elements like this.

```
graph1.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr({ cx: posX, cy: posY, r: 5 })
    .attr("class", "outer")
  .append("circle")
    .attr({ cx: posX, cy: posY, r: 2 })
    .attr("class", "inner");
```

But the second set doesn't show. I'm guessing they are there, somewhere, because running *d3.selectAll("circle")* gives me twice the size of the array. But I can't figure out where they are put. I suspect that they each one gets placed as a sub-tag to its corresponding viewed circle.

I also tried to split the statement in two like this.

```
graph1.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr({ cx: posX, cy: posY, r: 5 })
    .attr("class", "outer");
graph1.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr({ cx: posX, cy: posY, r: 2 })
    .attr("class", "inner");
```

It don't work, neither, and to be honest, I'm not sure if the *enter()* set still is valid as a bound reference set to the first circles... It seems that the whole set of the secondary circles gets outside the body of the document.

1. How do I get the secondary circles on the screen?
2. Should I prefer to *append().append()* or use separate statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you're nesting `circle` elements inside `circle` elements, which isn't allowed by the SVG specification.

In the second case, the `.data()` call in D3 matches the data you pass as an argument to the elements in the selection you've made before. When there are circles in the DOM already, those are selected, the data is matched to them, and the enter selection is empty.

To fix in your particular case (as you're using the same data), you can save the selection and operate on it several times:

```
var sel = graph1.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter();
sel.append("circle")...
sel.append("circle")...
```

Alternatively, you add a class that allows you to distinguish between the two sets of circles and modify your selector accordingly:

```
graph1.selectAll("circle.first").data(data).enter()
  .append("circle").attr("class", "first")...
graph1.selectAll("circle.second").data(data).enter()
  .append("circle").attr("class", "second")...
```